# Processing an Arraylist in intervals

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Strings, size of which may vary.

```
List<String> strList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For each of the Strings, I am calling a method **updateDetails(strList1),** which processes it and prints an op based on some logic.

I would like to call the above method updateDetails(strList1) for the first string, then for 5 (including first 1) etc in fixed intervals as below

The intervals are 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 1000

The o/p (if strList1 size is 25) should be something like:

```
Result for first 1:
Result for first 5:..
Result for first 10:..
Result for total 25 :
```

The o/p (if strList1 size is 9) should be something like:

```
Result for first 1:..
Result for first 5:..
Result for total 9:..
```

How to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid duplicates with

```
int len = strList1.size();
NavigableSet<Integer> sizes = new TreeSet<>();
sizes.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 1000, len));
for(int size: sizes.lower(len+1)) {
    List<String> list2 = strList1.subList(0, size);
    // process list2
}
```

---

If duplicates are not a problem.

```
int len = strList1.size();
for(int size: new int[] { 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 1000, len }) {
    if(size > len) continue;
    List<String> list2 = strList1.subList(0, size);
    // process list2
}
```

Comment: Your `if (size > len)` test prevents the last example in the OP from working - expected behaviour for `size > len` seems to be process all elements of the list.

Comment: @Thor84no perhaps you are thinking of `if (size >= len)` if `size` is `len` then `(size > len)` is false.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, that's not what it is. I was just looking at the first few iterations and missed that `len` is added at the end, so your code is somewhat confusingly looping the whole way through before it does the 3rd processing iteration.

Comment: @Thor84no that's so it always does the full length last.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know, I just said it was easy to miss. Oh, and now that I think about it, doesn't that mean that if `strList1.size() > 1000` you'll still be processing all of them (doesn't look like it should be from the question, but it's certainly not clear). Also, if `len` is a value that is already in the `int[]` you'll be doing it twice, right?

Comment: Correct, it will double up if the size is the same.  You could use a SortedSet instead to avoid this.

Comment: @Thor84no Have changed my answer based on your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Would something along these lines fullfill your requirements?

```
int[] intervals = new int[] {1, 5, 10, 50, ...}
for (int interval : intervals)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < interval && i < strList1.size(); i++)
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think -- making a bit of a guess about what `updateDetails()` does -- you should change its signature to:

```
Results updateDetails(Results accumulatedResults, List<String> items);
```

Define your own Results class appropriately and write a `toString()` for it. `updateDetails` calculates the results based on the previous results, and the new list. So for example, if it's supposed to be calculating the sum of the lengths of the strings:

```
Results updateDetails(Results accumulatedResults, List<String> items) {
     int sum = accumulatedResults.getSum();
     for(String item : items) {
        sum += item.length();
     }
     return new Results(sum);
}
```

This means that you're not repeating potentially expensive calculations.

Then your code needs to call this repeatedly:

```
Results results = new Results(); // start with an empty one
results = updateDetails(results,strings.subList(0,1));
System.out.println(results);
results = updateDetails(results,strings.subList(1,5));
System.out.println(results);
results = updateDetails(results,strings.subList(5,10));
System.out.println(results);
```

... and so on. Note, I think it's much better to have a function return a value, which you can print, than for a function to itself do the printing. It's more reusable, and more testable.

Of course you would do this in a loop:

```
Results results = new Results(); // start with an empty one
int[] sizes = new int[] { 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 1000 };
int last=0;
for(int i = 0; i<size.length; i++) {
    int size = sizes[i];
    results = updateDetails(results,strings.subList(last,size));
    System.out.println(results);
    last = size;
}
```

That's the basis. As written it will fail for an input list shorter than 1000. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to:

- Check whether size > strings.size() + 1
- if so, adjust size to strings.size() + 1 and make this the last iteration of the loop

(+1 because of how List.subList() works)

You also need to think about what happens for input lists longer than 1000. Perhaps it would be better to have a `sizeForIteration(int iteration)` method that handles arbitrarily large values for `iteration`, instead of the simple array lookup.

---

A simpler algorithm would be to put the knowledge of "report points" into your updateDetails logic.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size; i++) {
    // do something with list.get(i)
    if( sizes.contains(i) {
        System.out.println(something);
    }
}
System.out.println(something);
```

My main answer, although more complex, is more flexible I think.

Comment: But i am printing the results out from my updateDetails() method. Any issue in doing it?

Comment: @user1583803 in general I think it's a habit you should avoid. You get cleaner code by writing functions that return values, and have no side effects. Printing is a side effect. Do your IO in the top level of your program.

Comment: You should pass those parameters to your method. The only problem I see is you are iterating this list many times from the first position. This problem, though, can only be fixed modifying your updateDetails method. Merging that with your method is the solution.

Comment: @DavidFornas so i need to do the looping inside my updateDetails() method?

Comment: @user1583803 Yes, If it were a add (for example) you should add first 1, store it or print it; then add next 4 elements, store it or print it; then add next 5 elements, store it or print it; add next 15, add then store or print, etc. It's harder but should be way more efficient!

Comment: I'm confused about what you two are referring to. If you look at my example, there are two loops. One loop passes "chunks" of the sizes you've specified, to`updateDetails()`. The other loop is within `updateDetails()` and iterates through each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proccess 0 to 1, 2 to 9, 9 to 15, etc you can do that(which is c# but is very similar in Java)

```
        List<String> strList1 = new List<String>{"alfa","beta","gamma"};
        List<int> intervals= new List<int>{1,5,10,25,30};
        int index = 0, j=0;
        while (index<strList1.Count)
        {
            int from = index, to = index + intervals[j];
            doStuff(strList1, from, to);
            index +=intervals[j];
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: I want to process 0 to 1, 0 to 5, 0 to 10 etc

Comment: Yeah I figured out this later but maybe you would need that in the future. Let me know if the other answers doesn't meet your requirements.